# Change data target through Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on an AngularJS application and I have a task which is something like:
1) Click on a button.
2) If variableA === true, output a modal.
3) If variableA === false, go to another link without popping a modal.

Now, I am trying to achieve it with the following code

HTML:

```
<span id = "id1" ng-click="getClickType($event,row)" href=""> Text </span>
```

JS:

```
$scope.getClickType = function(event,row){
    $scope.activeElement = event.target;
    if(row.type == "A"){
        $scope.activeElement.dataset.target = "#ModalA";
        $scope.activeElement.dataset.toggle = "modal";
        /* Here I don't have to use the hack and the data target changes automatically and the modal pops up*/
    }
    else{
        someFunction().then(someOtherFunction);
    }
}

someOtherFunction(msg){
    if (msg.varA == true){
        var f1 = $scope.activeElement.dataset.target; //hack
        $scope.activeElement.dataset.target = "#ModalB";
        $scope.activeElement.dataset.toggle = "modal";
        if( f1 != $scope.activeElement.dataset.target){ //hack If statement
           $timeout(function () {
                            $scope.activeElement.click();
                       });
           /* Here i have use a hack and click on the element again to show the modal*/
        }
    }
    else{
        $scope.activeElement.dataset.target = "";
        $scope.activeElement.dataset.toggle = "";
        window.open(someURL);
        /* works fine*/
    }
}
```

So you can see, I am using a hack for ModalB. Changing the dataset.target in the someOtherFucntion() does not pop up the modal. I have to click on the the active element again for it to show.

My question is:
Why do I need to click on the activeElement again to change the data target.
Why is it only required in the second function.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What is going on in someFunction? Is it a angularjs like promise e.g. $q or $http?
Did you try to execute modalB stuff in $scope.$apply function?

There is a trick when you accidentally get out from angular scope or you executing non angular script

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.activeElement.dataset.target = "#ModalB";
    $scope.activeElement.dataset.toggle = "modal";
 }
```

or you can call $scope.$apply right after open ModalB

```
$scope.activeElement.dataset.target = "#ModalB";
$scope.activeElement.dataset.toggle = "modal";
$scope.$apply()
```

This will force angular to perform digest and make checks.
BUT there is one pitfall in this, if you are in angular context it may already performing digest loop, it will throw an error informing you that this process is already in progress so your error is somewhere else.

Comment: Hi, In someFunction, I am calling a stored procedure from the database which then returns a promise to someOtherFunction with the resultset (msg). Could you please explain to me "Did you try to execute modalB stuff in $scope.$apply function"? How can I achieve that? -Thanks

Comment: One other thing, is this promise is handled by $http? If not, i'm suggesting wrap this promise with $q.when method: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when

Comment: Hi, it is being handled by $http. I cannot make any changes as it being used by all the controllers in the application. I tried to run the statements under $scope.$apply and also ran $scope.$apply after changing the dataset target but to no avail. Even if I am using the hack, I just would like to understand why it is happening.

Comment: I created plunker for this, can you help me broke it?
https://plnkr.co/edit/WIhYoe?p=preview